# Where this typescript error in nuxt.confing.ts from?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

My package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/apollo": "^5.0.0-alpha.5",
    "@nuxtjs/html-validator": "^1.2.3",
    "nuxt": "^3.1.0",
    "nuxt-purgecss": "^2.0.0",
    "nuxt-svgo": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

Nuxt.config.ts

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  typescript: {
    strict: true,
    shim: true,
  },
  modules: [
    "@nuxtjs/apollo",
    "nuxt-purgecss",
    "@nuxtjs/html-validator",
    "nuxt-svgo",
  ],
  apollo: {
    clients: {
      default: {
        httpEndpoint: "https://api.github.com/graphql",
      }
    }
  },
});
```

I'm getting the error in Modules field, it says:

> Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.ts(2589)

Also I have one more error in tsconfing.json

> Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.   The file is in the
> program because:
> Entry point of type library 'node' specified in compilerOptionsts